# How would I mount a remote server so it persists after a reboot?

Tags: server, mount, automount

On Ubuntu server 12.04 I can run the following command to mount a remote directory:

```
sshfs root@192.168.1.1:/w/common/Rotas/Nurses /home/danny/nurserotas/
```

I am then prompted for the password for the remote server (192.168.1.1).

How could I run the above command, including the password entry, whenever the server boots?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by editing /etc/fstab

This thread should be helpful: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1173714